Custom function into custom php file | Wordpress
I have a file called custom_functions.php with all my functions used to my page test.php.
If I insert this code into functions.php, it works well
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/class/custom_functions.php';

But I want that this file is called only for page test.php.
I made some changes and inserted this code into functions.php
function load_test() {
    if (is_page('test')) {
        require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/class/custom_functions.php';
    }
    
}

add_action('wp', 'load_test');


But still not working,maybe I do something wrong

is your test.php page an actual page in wp with a slug of "test"?

Yes, my permalink is https://mywebsite.it/test. if I insert many debugs, I show that load_test is called 2 times. In the first time, enter into if conditions; in the second, go out.

"But I want that this file is called only for page test.php" - Are you doing that for a very specific reason, and if so, is it something related to performance, and if so, have you actually confirmed that it is a performance problem when loading on other pages? The other reason that I can think of is that beyond functions, it also contains hooks that call the functions, is that the case?

Hello, all functions present on it are specific to my page. I don't want other pages to load that function

Why not is_page() or if it's a page template is_page_template()? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ - Also as Chris Haas asks, why? Unless there is something that's affecting performance, this seems unnecessary.

"I don't want other pages to load that function" - I apologize for belaboring the point, I just don't want you chasing a micro-optimization if that's what this is. I just performed a very simple test and looking just at functions and classes that start with wp_, WordPress  core loads almost 1,000 functions and 200 classes on every page load. Unless you are also hooking, I don't think you will notice these extra functions. But I'll leave it at that, and won't bug you about it any more.

I would definitely agree with @disinfor as it relates to is_page_template(). In the long run the slug and title-based things break down, and your life can often be made easier my making some UI controllable way to designate a page as being special. Often people will then say "but I don't trust my users", to which I empathize, but these same users have permission to delete their home page and break their entire site, so this isn't really any different than that.
